# Laravel Route Not Defined Exception

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I want to post data to insert a user. The following is a code snippet in HTML which is going to be used for adding a user.

```html
<form id="register-form" action="{{ route('register.add') }}" method="post" role="form" style="display: none;">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" tabindex="1" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" value="">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="email" name="email" id="email" tabindex="1" class="form-control" placeholder="Email Address" value="">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="password" name="password" id="password" tabindex="2" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="password" name="confirm-password" id="confirm-password" tabindex="2" class="form-control" placeholder="Confirm Password">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
                <input type="submit" name="register-submit" id="register-submit" tabindex="4" class="form-control btn btn-register" value="Register Now">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

**Route**

```php
Route::resource('register', 'PassportController');
```

**ProductController**

```php
public function add(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'name' => 'required|min:3',
        'email' => 'required|email|unique:users',
        'password' => 'required|min:6',
    ]);

    $user = User::create([
        'name' => $request->name,
        'email' => $request->email,
        'password' => bcrypt($request->password)
    ]);

    $token = $user->createToken('TutsForWeb')->accessToken;

    return response()->json(['token' => $token], 200);
}
```

When I run my server it throws an exception.

> Route [register.add] not defined. (View:
>   \apiauthexample\resources\views\welcome.blade.php)

Comment: Run this `php artisan route:list` in your terminal, and see your routes. As I see it's not `register.add` but `register.store`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because Laravel's resource controllers doesn't feature `add()` actions. `Route::resource` method registers `index`, `create`, `store`, `show`, `edit`, `update` and `destroy` routes. You can read more about it in the [official documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/controllers#resource-controllers).

Judging by your case you need to rename your `add` method to `store` and reference this route by `route('register.store')`.